# A particular MySQL table queries are taking too long

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've got a tiny log table. It takes too long to get the answer, especially for the first time. All other database tables are working great. Could you guess what might be wrong here?

```
mysql> select count(id) from log_error;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|     98187 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1 min 37.39 sec)



mysql> show create table log_error;

| log_error | CREATE TABLE `log_error` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_time` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `prefix` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_log_level` (`level`),
  KEY `idx_log_category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=575504 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |

1 row in set (0.04 sec)



mysql> select count(id) from log_error;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|     98187 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.57 sec)



mysql> explain select count(id) from log_error;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | log_error | NULL       | index | NULL          | idx_log_level | 5       | NULL | 95044 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks, I have updated the question with the Explain query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by changing table engine from InnoDB to MyISAM:

```
ALTER TABLE log_error ENGINE = MyISAM;


mysql> select count(*) from log_error;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   232213 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```